# UINavigationController with UIStatusBar and without UIStatusBar on iOS 7

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uistatusbar

Is it possible programatically switch UIStatusBar background form transparent to UINavigationController's UINavigationBar tintColor and back on iOS 7?

Comment: Changing the background color from transparent to the bar color will do nothing, as the status bar sits above the nav bar already.

Or are you asking if its possible to change the status bar style (i.e. the foreground colors)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Apple answered, you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have demonstrated how this new method, preferredStatusBarStyle, can be overridden to adjust the color of the content in the status bar iOS7.

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
     return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Returning UIStatusBarStyleLightContent changes the color of the content in the status bar to white; alternately, UIStatusBarStyleDefault sets the color of the status bar content to black . Black and white are currently the only available status bar content colors.